# JFrog Artifactory or JFrog Bintray , when to use one over the other?

Tags: continuous-integration, artifacts, artifactory

We are actually looking for a package management system for our project.
The target is simple, have a centralized system to keep our packages ( apps and middlewares ) and use them with our CI/CD tools (Jenkins, Ansible, Docker ...)

Looking for options I discovered [JFrog Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/) and [JFrog Bintray](https://bintray.com/). they both seems to do the same job but I don't believe JFrog is maintaining two concurrent products with the same options.

What is the difference between Artifactory and Bintray?
How do we choose one over the other and why?

Comment: Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877177/what-is-the-difference-between-jfrog-artifactory-and-bintray/38979659#38979659) to the similar question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[JFrog Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/) and [JFrog Bintray](https://www.jfrog.com/bintray/) both manage binaries (and any other file type you can think of). I'd like to see them as two different parts of your CI/CD pipeline.

**Artifactory** is mostly meant to be used inside the organization. For managing all binaries coming in as dependencies (like maven central jars) and being produced by your build process (like your `pack.rpm` or `org/pack-docker` docker image). These can later be used by others in the org or released to **Bintray**.

**Bintray** is meant to provide a universal distribution platform for your end deliverables. For example, the `pack.rpm` you want to be available for your customers to download. And also that `org/pack-docker` docker image.

Look into the features lists of each and see how they differ in order to best match their intended role.

- [Artifactory features](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/features/)
- [Bintray features](https://jfrog.com/bintray/features/)

I hope this helps explaining the differences.

**Disclosure**: I work at JFrog

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:**

- **Bintray**

  1. Software for other people's use.
  2. Publishing platform
  3. Released software
  4. Selective, distributed, download optimized, network heavy
- **Artifactory**

  1. Software for your own use.
  2. Caching platform
  3. All derived objects and binary dependencies for CI/CD
  4. Inclusive, centralized, upload optimized, storage heavy

**Disclosure**: JFrog did not offer me a job. :)

Comment: regarding the disclosure, it's not too late :)